# Declaring a class type variable in Typescript

Tags: class, typescript, object, types

I'm having trouble understanding line 18 of the following snippet of a [TypeScript tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

```js
1   class Greeter {
2       static standardGreeting = "Hello, there";
3       greeting: string;
4       greet() {
5           if (this.greeting) {
6               return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
7           }
8           else {
9               return Greeter.standardGreeting;
10          }
11      }
12  }
13  
14  let greeter1: Greeter;
15  greeter1 = new Greeter();
16  console.log(greeter1.greet());
17  
18  let greeterMaker: typeof Greeter = Greeter;
19  greeterMaker.standardGreeting = "Hey there!";
20  
21  let greeter2: Greeter = new greeterMaker();
22  console.log(greeter2.greet());
```

As I understand from the tutorial, the goal of the declaration of `greatermaker` is getting the Greeter class type into a variable, rather than the instance type.

Firstly, what is the function of the assignment operator `=` in this line?

Secondly, what do we mean exactly with the distinction between the class type and the instance type?
  I guess, in the first we are able to manipulate the static member variables as opposed to the second?

**Edit.**

Why don't we just use `let greeterMaker: typeof Greeter`, that is without the assignment operator?

Comment: Assignment sets a value and colon only sets the type. So if you intend to use the greetmaker for anything it has to be assigned. But why do typeof Greeter. That will be a string and not the type since javascript has no types in that sense. Just do ```let greetmaker: Greeter = Greeter;```. Or simply remove the type declaration since the assignment will do that implicitly.

Comment: I think I now understand my confusion with this line.
Am I correct that line 18 is equivalent with the following two lines:
`let greeterMaker : typeof Greeter;
`greetermaker = Greeter;`?

Comment: Mark as solved and upvote relevant answers please.

Comment: @JGoodgive My confusion isn't fully resolved yet, actually. I'll accept when it is. An upvote is at my own discretion.

Comment: @JGoodgive *But why do typeof Greeter. That will be a string and not the type since javascript has no types in that sense.* What was the rationale in the tutorial to use `typeof`, given your note that typeof, indeed, only returns a string in this case?

Comment: Typeof is a javascript function (where the concept of typescript types doesnt exist) that gives us the basic type of things to let us check if something is one of the basic types such as object, undefined, NaN, number, string, boolean and function. For that it is sometimes useful but not within the context of tyoescript classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163490/discussion-between-musse-redi-and-jgoodgive).

Answer (score 3):

The goal is to have the reference copy of the `Greeter` class (actually function) into the variable `greeterMaker`. With these you have 2 variables `greeterMaker` and `Greeter` to refer to the same class. So you can create objects of that class via

```
new Greeter()
```

or

```
new greeterMaker()
```

These two statements will do the same thing, because `greeterMaker` is just another variable which refers to the `Greeter`.

Comment: Why do we need the assignment operator in the declaration of `greaterMaker`? What would be wrong with the declaration `let greeterMaker: typeof Greeter`?

Comment: It will just set the type to the `Greeter`, but not assign the value to it. Think about `let str: string` - `str` in this case is `undefined`

Comment: Type assignment only helps the typscript compiler understand your code. The value assignment is needed to actually get anything besides undefined. So a class is both a javascript function that lets you create a prototypal object AND in typescript it is a type, the type of the returned object from that fuction, but only in the typescript compiler. So assigning types really doesnt do anything except helps the compiler catch errors.

Comment: @JGoodgive Okay, I think I get it now.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan My confusion revolves around the use of `typeof`. Could you address the use of `typeof`? As @JGoodgive noted, shouldn't it just be `let greetermaker : Greeter = Greeter`; i.e. without the `typeof` Javascript construct?

Comment: No. `Greeter` says that your type is of type `Greeter` instance, not the type which creates `Greeter` types. So `Greeter` and `typeof Greeter` are different. In your example you can not do `new greeter1()`.

Answer (score 0):

(Tentative) expansion of @JGoodgive's comment.

An important thing to note is the distinction bewteen:

- the TypeScript type reference `Greeter`, as in `let var : Greeter`;
- the JavaScript instance type of class `Greeter`, as in `var = new Greeter; typeof var;`
- the JavaScript class type variable, which embodies the class constructor itself, as in `var = Greeter`.

It is key to note that the class type variable `var = Greeter` is in fact the class constructor function. Hence, it is, incidentally and in particluar, of type `Greeter`; because that is the class of which it is a *public* member function.

On another note, `typeof Greeter` should return `Greeter` according to the tutorial. This is because by `Greeter` in  `typeof Greeter`, we mean the constructor function of the class `Greeter`. And since, the constructor function returns the class itself (as an instance), it [the constructor function `Greeter`] is of class type `Greeter`, indeed.